# Avoid event grab during motion in Tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, python-3.4

Is it possible in Tkinter to avoid the event grab which occures when you press a mouse button over a widget and keep it pressed while you move the mouse?

I want to register the mouse button and then track all widgets the user enters while he moves his mouse with the button pressed. When the user releases the mouse button the application executes the same action for all tracked widgets.

The following code should explain what I want to do.

```
# Set a tracking flag
widget.bind('<Button>', start_tracking)
# Add the entered widget to the tracked widgets, if the tracking flag is set
widget.bind('<Enter>', add_to_tracked_widgets)
# Execute an action for every tracked widget; unset the flag
widget.bind('<ButtonRelease>', end_tracking)
```

I took a look at the `grab_current` and `grab_status` methods, but they always returned `None`.

Python version is 3.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the most complicated way to do this, but okay.
One thing that makes this more complicated is Tkinter itself, because `event.widget` still refers to the widget that was clicked on initally. A different event we can use is `Motion` which is activated when the mouse moves inside a widget.

```
tk.bind("<Motion>", add_tracked)
```

I think you can implement the list and state variables yourself, so we come to the `add_tracked` method (I just renamed it, it's your `add_to_tracked_widgets`):

```
def add_tracked(event):
    if tracking:
        # Get coordinated of the event and use the master window method to determine
        # wich widget lays inside these.
        widget = tk.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        # Since 'Motion' creates many events repeatedly, you have to convert this
        # list into a set to remove duplicates.
        widgets.append(widget)
```

Comment: Jeah, I figured this way out for myself but I thought there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: Nah, I don't think so :/

Comment: Btw. `motion` only is thrown if a mouse button is pressed, so there is no need for the `if tracking`; also instead of using a `list` a `set` would handle the duplicate entries on itself.

Comment: 1. Not for me :S  It's always thrown here, regardless of any other events. 2. Uh yes, thanks^^